# How to update a table line by line using another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a table field using another table with the row number as my index.

Table 1.

```
|QuestionKey | Value |
|    Q31     |   1   |
|    Q33     |   3   |
|    Q44     |   5   |
```

Table 2.

```
|Id | Value|
| 1 |   3  |
| 2 |   4  |
| 3 |   1  |
```

I want to update the values from table 1 using the table 2, matching rows by the position.
Me and my coworker already try the following query:

```
set @rank=0;
update table1 j
set j.`Value` = (SELECT a.Value from table2 a WHERE a.id = @rank:=@rank+1)
```

Using this query the mysql point me the error: Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Anyone knows how could I do this or what is wrong with my query?

Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `where` clause is evaluated multiple times.  I supposed you could solve the problem by using `limit`.  Another way is to be explicit about the joins and relationships between the tables:

```
update table1 t join
       (select t.*, @rank := @rank + 1 as seqnum
        from table1 t cross join (select @rank := 0) vars
        order by QuestionKey
       ) tt
       on tt.QuestionKey = t.QuestionKey join
       table2 t2
       on t2.id = tt.seqnum
  set t.`Value` = t2.Value;
```

Comment: Thnak you :). It worked well with some modification to my context.